# How to ignore JFrame opacity?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, awt

I need to achieve the effect of "lights off" while displaying animation. It's currently been done with transparent Jframe, black background with 50% opacity the size of the monitor. then, there is this canvas component which should draw RGB**A** buffered-image.

Problems pops up when the the JFrame opacity effects the Canvas as well, making it semi transparent. That's what i'm trying to avoid.

```
//** Window class extends Canvas

public Window(){

    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    int hostMonitorWidth = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int hostMonitorHeight = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(hostMonitorWidth, hostMonitorHeight);
    super.setPreferredSize(dimension);

    window = new JFrame();
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setOpacity(0.55f);
    window.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    window.setSize(hostMonitorWidth, hostMonitorHeight);
    window.add(this);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.requestFocus();
    window.setFocusableWindowState(true);


    super.createBufferStrategy(3);
}

public void draw(){
    BufferStrategy buffer = super.getBufferStrategy();
    java.awt.Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,0, super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
    g.drawImage(batch.getImage(), 0, 0, super.getWidth(), super.getHeight(), null);

    g.dispose();
    buffer.show();
}
```

I have tried couple combinations of the following code with Jpanel, Layered Panes, Jlabel and what not. It's always seems to keep the opacity / throwing unexplainable exceptions / not working for any reason.

Am i doing it the correct way? what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `setOpacity`, use `setBackground` on the `JFrame` and pass it a alpha based color. This will allow the frame to become transparent without affecting the other components.

You may, however, find that `Canvas` doesn't like alpha based colors (as it only has an opaque state)

Comment: I have already tried that, it seems like the backgroud color takes over the canvas. could you show how it should be done the properway?

Comment: And, as I said `Canvas` might not like what you're doing, as it only has an opaque state (it doesn't support transparency), if you want to paint a translucent component, you will need to use a Swing based component instead

Comment: what is your best suggestion?

Comment: Use a Swing based component, like `JComponent` or `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method, painting your translucent effect within them (remember to set the components to transparent, `setOpaque(false)`), something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329710/what-can-be-used-to-prompt-translucent-window-or-notification-screenshot-exampl/34330165#34330165) for example

Comment: will do, much appreciated.